# Adding HttpClientFactory to an ABP Core Project yields a "Cannot access a disposed object" on the second call

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I've added a HttpClientFactory Implementation into my ASPNet Boilerplate Core project to make a call out to a Rest Service. The first call works fine, but I get a "Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: Framework.CorrelationIdDelegatingHandler'." error on the second call.

I've tried the same code in a new .Net Core project and it works fine.

The HttpClientFactory implementation I've used is from here:

https://rehansaeed.com/optimally-configuring-asp-net-core-httpclientfactory/

I'm not sure what I need to change to correct this, any help much appreciated.

I'm using ABP version 4.7.1 and Asp.Net Core 2.2

ConfigureServices additions:

```
services.AddCorrelationId();
services.AddPolicies(this._appConfiguration);
services.AddHttpClient<IExternalBoClient, ExternalBoClient,    ExternalBoClientOptions>(_appConfiguration, nameof(ApplicationOptions.ExternalBoClient));
```

AddHttpClient implementation:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddHttpAuthenticationClient<TClient, TImplementation, TClientOptions>(
                                                                                        this IServiceCollection services,
                                                                                        IConfiguration configuration,
                                                                                                string configurationSectionName
                                                                                    )
        where TClient : class
        where TImplementation : class, TClient
        where TClientOptions : HttpClientOptions, new() =>
        services
            .Configure<TClientOptions>(configuration.GetSection(configurationSectionName))
            .AddTransient<CorrelationIdDelegatingHandler>()
            .AddTransient<UserAgentDelegatingHandler>()
            .AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>()
            .ConfigureHttpClient((sp, options) =>
            {
                var httpClientOptions = sp
                    .GetRequiredService<IOptions<TClientOptions>>()
                    .Value;
                options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
                options.BaseAddress = httpClientOptions.BaseAddress;
                if (httpClientOptions.Timeout.TotalSeconds > 0)
                    options.Timeout = httpClientOptions.Timeout;
            })
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(x => new DefaultHttpClientHandler())
            .AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry(PolicyName.HttpRetry)
            .AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry(PolicyName.HttpCircuitBreaker)
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<CorrelationIdDelegatingHandler>()
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<UserAgentDelegatingHandler>()
            .Services;
```

Comment: We need to see your actual code. Especially your `ConfigureServices` method. Do you have any custom `DelegatingHandler` instances?

Comment: What happens if you don't add any of the Polly delegating-handler items to the client pipeline?

Comment: Taking out the delegate handlers avoids the error. But need to get it working with the delegate handlers included please:

Comment: Hi Guys, any help on this, I can't see why adding DelegatingHandlers in a Abp Boilerplate project would result in this error.

Comment: Hi Guys, still having this issue. Implementing HttpClientFactory in a new .net core project without Abp Boilerplate seems to work fine, but when I use it in my abp boilerplate project I get the "Cannot access a disposed object" exception. There seems to be something in the abp framework that is conflicting ? Any ideas please? Cheers

Comment: What I'm finding is that I only get the  "Cannot access a disposed object" error when I make the second call out to the rest service within 2 minutes of the previous call. If i wait more than 2 mins then the second call work fine ?

Comment: The 2-minute timeout is because the default `IHttpClientFactory` implementation caches `HttpClientHandler` instances for 2 minutes.